# Custom Logging information

Tags: wixsharp

I'm new to wix#, and wanted to know if you can either have a custom log file creation or if you can inject messages into the process.

I find that the log files are not as detailed as I would like.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add to the log, use session.Log

```
session.Log("Begin MyAction Hello World");
```

[Here is a](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/issues/118) reference as well